# React Native unable to run a successful fetch to express API

Tags: node.js, api, express, react-native

Given the following setup:

**server.js**

```
const express = require('express')
const path = require('path')
const app = express()
const cors = require('cors')
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080

app.use(cors())

app.get('/api', (req, res) => {
  res.send({code: 200, message: 'I have arrived!'})
})

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`I can hear your thoughts on ${port}`))
```

and the presentational component with call:

**App.js**

```
componentDidMount() {
  fetch(`/api`, {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json'
    }
  }).then(res => {
    console.log(res)
    return res.json()
  }).then(response => {
    console.log(response)
    this.data = response
  }).catch(error => {
    this.error = error.message || error.error
  })
}
```

**package.json:**

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "npm-run-all --parallel start:client start:server",
  "start:client": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
  "start:server": "node server.js",
  "test": "jest"
},
```

I am running the app via `yarn start`, and I see the log: "I can hear your thoughts"...  **The fetch call, however, is never made**.  If I supply another fully qualified url within the fetch call it returns the data as expected, however I am unable to hit the express api from within the component.

- If I place `http://localhost:8080/api` in the browser I get the response.
- If I place `http://localhost:8080/api` in the fetch call it is never called (or at least doesn't appear to be).

**How can I properly configure this to call the express api when running locally?**

As always any and all direction is appreciated, so thanks in advance!

Comment: Your issue is caused by using the term `localhost` in your api call. You need to use the ip address of your computer. Something like  `192.168.###.###/api/` or whatever your ip address is

Comment: Unfortunately, replacing with the IP within the fetch URL has the same result.

Comment: Is your component definitely being mounted?  If so are you getting any errors from the fetch request?  Have you tried adding additional logging on your server to see if the request is getting to it? Have you tried a different api end point like `'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1'`?

Comment: It s not in the above code but I am logging componentDidMount, so yes it is mounting.
There is no network log at all currently.

As stated: 

```...If I supply another fully qualified url within the fetch call it returns the data as expected``` 
- so yes I have attempted that as well.

```{userId: 1, id: 1, title: "delectus aut autem", completed: false}``` is logged via the supplied url.  Can it be something a miss with the debug server and attempting to run the express server as well?

Comment: `react-native` or `expo`?

Comment: React Native, just a default init app

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189329/discussion-between-andrew-and-studiobrain).

Comment: So the issue is still evident in Android.  iOS works as expected in all scenarios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the issue for this is two fold.

---

Firstly you are running the server and the bundler in the same terminal window. I believe that this is causing them to get confused.

Run them in separate windows. Yes that means you have to run an extra command but it will mean that you will be able to clearly see the logs for each of them.

Also you may have to restart you bundler, especially when you add new packages which will mean restarting your server.

Similarly when you update your server you will have to restart it also causing you to restart your bundler. It doesn't seem like a good idea running them in the same window.

---

Secondly you are using the `localhost` for the api. This works nicely on your computer because the api is running on your computer's `localhost` so it can find it. However, when you run it on a device and you use `localhost` it looks for the api on your device's localhost and cannot find it there, thus it doesn't bring back a result.

---

Your solution is quite clear. Firstly, run your bundler and your server in different terminal windows. And secondly use the ip address of your computer so that the emulator/simulator can easily find where the api is located.

I copied your code and made only two changes to the `react-native` code.

1. Added alerts to show the `response` and `error` from the `fetch` request
2. Used my local ip address of my computer rather than `localhost`

Here are some images of me running it on both Android and iOS, using your code and the changes that I detailed above.

## Android

[image: running on android]

## iOS

[image: running on ios]

Comment: thanks for your detailed answer. It will help others that may come accross the same issue. IP and separate tabs is definitely the solution (at least when in development mode). On a bonus, I am now using a package called `ttabs` which will open a new terminal window via npm scripts: ```"tab:server": "ttab -t 'api server' npm run start:server"```